# Getter and Setter return null in Android

Tags: java, android

so I've been working on a project that receives data from server, for example sessionKey. I created getter and setter method like this :

```
public class sEngine
{
private static String sessionKey;

public static String getSessionKey() {
        return sessionKey;
    }

    public static void setSessionKey(
            String sessionKey) {
        sEngine.sessionKey = sessionKey;
    }
}
```

Then I have activity A. In this activity A, I insert a value into the setter method.

```
public class A extends Activity
{
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

sEngine.setSessionKey("Hello world")
}
}
```

I also have activity B. In this activity B, I call the getter method

```
public class B extends Activity
{
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            String sessionKey = sEngine.getSessionKey();
    }
}
```

It occurs to me, that Android sometimes wipes all the data in order to free some memory, for example when I let the program idle for too long, or I used Advanced Task Killer. The problem is if those happen,  I will get null in activity B when I call the getter method although I've set the value in activity A. Is there any way for me to maintain the value stored via the setter method (other than using SharedPreference) so the value will still be there although Android wipes the memories/data?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use SharedPreferences? It's easy to use, safe from this issue *and* it's a commonly accepted approach.

Comment: Make your `sEngine` as singleton. Hope it may help you.

Comment: You can also save the data in the Bundle

Comment: Why not use persistent storage? SharedPrefs or SQLite database are the most common for this type of thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way for me to maintain the value stored via the setter
>   method (other than using SharedPreference) so the value will still be
>   there although Android wipes the memories/data?

Not sure why you wouldn't want to use `SharedPreferences`, despite it being the perfect candidate in your requirement. When somethings as simple as this can store it:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(SOME_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
editor.putString("session_key", sessionKey );
```

This will ensure your *sessionkey* always remains stored for easy retrieval. Unless the user clears your app data that is.

Your only alternatives as opposed to `SharedPreferences` are saving the *sessionkey* to a `Database` which in my opinion, considering the task it will perform, is absolutely unnecessary.

You could also consider *writing* the *sessionkey* to a *text file* and then *read* it to retrive the data.

Both the alternatives to `SharedPreferences` are truly unfit for the purpose you need it for. And I would really urge you to re-consider using `SharedPreferences` .

Comment: +1. Persistent storage is the safest way if you want to prevent data loss as much as possible. Yes the user can clear your app data, but they can just as easily FC the app, wiping the static String. You could also do cloud storage ;)

Comment: @A--C: That is what I find interesting about the OP not wanting to use such a useful feature.

Comment: @SiddhartLele  Yeah, my bad. Actually SharedPreferences comes to mind, but I thought it was a bad approach to save each variable using SharedPreferences, because I still have around 12 variables stored with getter setter method like this. So I was looking for another simpler and better approach. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @WandyWijayanto: I store and retrieve 10 variables for Facebook and Twitter session details and have never seen a slow down because of that, nor has one been reported. If that was your concern, then rest assured. It is fast. And I'm glad I could help. :-)

Comment: @SiddhartLele Yes, that is one of my concern. The second is, if I call from SharedPreferences, I will need Context and that means I have to change a lot of my code, meanwhile I was limited by time. Editing it will consume time, which there are so many. CMIIW, because maybe I am just having a bad structure of program.

Comment: @WandyWijayanto: If you are saving it somewhere, you will have to retrieve it anyway. If it needs a little restructuring, then so be it. I am sure it will be for the best. You could create a `public class` for storing and retrieving your details from the `SharedPreferences` file. That will be one less thing to worry about. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Declare you non activity class in A Activity. and then set your session value.

```
sEngine mengine = new sEngine();
mengine.setSessionKey("Hello world");
```

And also get session value in B activity.

```
sEngine mengine = new sEngine();
String str = mengine.getSessionKey();
```

Comment: You're making new instances. If the String is still `static` this would have the same issue. If the String isn't static, you'd be making two separate Objects each with a different `sessionKey`. A singleton approach might work, but it will also most likely be killed off on low memory situations and when it is recreated, the String will be `null` again.

Comment: dont use static value. public String sessionKey is enough

Comment: And how do you expect two separate Instances to have the same `sessionKey`? From my comment: *If the String isn't static, you'd be making two separate Objects each with a different `sessionKey`.*

Answer (score 0):

change

```
sEngine.sessionKey = sessionKey;
```

in your code to

```
this.sessionKey = sessionKey;
```

**or** simply

```
sessionKey = sessionKey;
```

using `sEngine.` makes one believe that your class is static.Which it isnt!

**or** if you want to use this `sEngine.` everywhere in your code you need to declare this class as `static`.In that case you just need to make the class declaration to static:

```
public static class sEngine {
```

Comment: *`public static class sEngine`* please read up on what a static class actually is. You do **not** have to declare a class as static (and actually can't for a top level class) to allow use of static members. Doing `sEngine.sessionKey` is perfectly valid because the class member is static, and so, `ClassName.memberName` is alright and **doesn't** mean that the class is static.